# Leave-one-subject-out cross validation in Caret

Tags: r, sampling, cross-validation, caret

**Hi Dear Colleagues,**

I wonder how to correctly setup a leave-one-subject-out cross validation (LOSO) for train() function in caret.

Here is my example code:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(rnorm(1:500,1),rnorm(1:500,10),rnorm(1:500,5),
          rnorm(1:500,100),c(rep('1',100),rep('2',100),rep('3',100),rep('4',100),
                                rep('5',100)),rep(c(rep('X0',50),rep('X1',50)),5)))

colnames(dat) <- c('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'subject','class')
```

What would you then specify in trainControl() instead of cv (LOGCV?)? How would you modify the following code?

```
svmFit <- train(dat,y,
                method = "svmRadial",
                preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                tuneGrid = MySVMTuneGrid,
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, classProbs =  TRUE))
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 3):

If there is one subject per row, then `method = LOOCV` would do it. You will have to setup your own resampling indicators and supply them via `index`. At that point, the value of `method` does't matter.

You could do something like:

```
subs <- unique(dat$subject)
model_these <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(subs))
for(i in seq_along(subs)) 
   model_these[[i]] <- which(dat$subject != subs[i])
names(model_these) <- paste0("Subject", subs)
svmFit <- train(class ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4,
                data = dat,
                method = "svmRadial",
                preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                tuneGrid = MySVMTuneGrid,
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", 
                                         index = model_these, 
                                         classProbs =  TRUE))
```

(note that your test data set converts `var`-`var4` to character, so I didn't test this.)

Max

Comment: i have a problem when i run this code. Error: `index` should be lists of integers.That error appears.